# Extracting Excel data into pipe delimited file - How to refer to other workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on creating excel file, that includes only button that, when clicked on, extracts all other excel files in specified (now just hardcoded) directory into pipe delimited .txt files. I did some programming in the past but I am not familiar much with VBA, so I usually work by searching and reusing tutorials and such.

Basicaly what I want to do is:
- Loop through specific directory
- For each xls/xlsx file, create separate .txt pipe delimited extract of the same name with .txt extension

So far, I got to this code:

```
    Sub Run_Coversion()

Dim directory As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim OutputFile As String

Dim myWkBook As Workbook
Dim myRecord As Range
Dim myField As Range
Dim nFileNum As Long
Dim sOut As String
Const DELIMITER As String = "|"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = "C:\Users\vacek\Documents\EFPIA_Project\Excel_Tool\Files\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xls*")
Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
OutputFile = directory & fileName & ".txt"
nFileNum = FreeFile
Open OutputFile For Output As #1
Set myWkBook = Workbooks(fileName)
myWkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    With myRecord
        For Each myField In Range(.Cells, Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myField.Text
        Next myField
        Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
        sOut = Empty
    End With
Next myRecord
End With

Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The problem is, that the "For each" loop goes through workbook that is running the macro, not the one, that is opened. I experimented with setting active of that workbook, but I cannot make it working. Can anyone help me to set this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a reference to the worksheet in the opened workbook:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = myWkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Then use that variables `Range/Row/Cell ...` properties in the subsequent code to prevent a "naked" `Range` defaulting to the `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
For Each myRecord In sheet.Range("A1:A" & sheet.Range("A" & sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    ...
```

Comment: It works! Didn't know where to put the references and where not to. Now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Sheet1 as Object    
Set Sheet1 = [Object].Application.Workbooks("filename").WorkSheets("Sheet1")
```

you can do it like this also

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar, though in my case the delimiter in question was `>` and I was importing a .txt file as if it were a .csv.

I used the `Workbooks.OpenText` method, with the parameter `DataType:=xlDelimited`. To set a delimiter other than tab or comma or semicolon, I set the `Other` and `OtherChar` parameters to `Other:=True, OtherChar:=">"`.

This worked for me; perhaps it will work just as well for `OtherChar:="|"`?